# how to identify a device and use a code for a pc device and a second code for mobile(ios or android)?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, mobile

I'm trying to add a code (php, js, jquery with redirect page) that identify a pc, laptop or a mobile device and redirect a pc/laptop into a one page code and a second page code for a mobile.

Meaning the pc/laptop will have his code and the mobile will have a different code.

Comment: http://webdesign.about.com/od/mobile/a/detect-mobile-devices.htm

Answer (score 0):

Am using the following option to detect mobile device and redirect to another page

```
<?php
$iphone = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], "iPhone");
$android = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], "Android");
$palmpre = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], "webOS");
$berry = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], "BlackBerry");
$ipod = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], "iPod");

if ($iphone || $android || $palmpre || $ipod || $berry == true) {
header('Location: http://YOUR PAGE LINK/test/');
}
?>
```

this is the location of page to be redirect

```
 header('Location: http://YOUR PAGE LINK/test/');
```